# How to decrypt a known cipher text with brute force attack?

Tags: java, encryption

can anyone answer to my question..

If i have an already known cipher text and the only information that i know is that the

plaintext is English language message.I dont know the plaintext,only that is english language message.

The key is 16-bit.

Which is the procedure that i should follow if i want to decrypt it with *brute force
 attack*??

Comment: Is this for good or evil?

Comment: Do you know the algorithm it was encrypted with?

Comment: This sounds very similar to a project euler problem I solved recently.
Perhaps looking at peoples solutions to [this just for fun puzzle](http://projecteuler.net/problem=59) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This strongly depends on the encryption-algorithm. If your message was encrypted with and key of the same length by xoring each letter, you have no chance to decrypt the message. The One-Time-Pad is a perfect secure encryption method (at least if it's used only for one encryption).

In case the message was encrypted with a non-perfect-secure method you should iterate over the key-space (the space all possible keys for encryption live in). Afterwards you have to check whether the resulting decrypted message is plausible to be the original message. For that you could check whether a dictonary contains substring of your candidate.

Again, it's pretty hard to describe a way to decrypt your message without any knowledge of the algorithm which was used for encryption.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fully automate the brute forcing, you need to know when the brute forcing/decryption has been successful - that is, you need to keep checking the decryption output and match it against a long dictionary of English words. If there is a strong match for the plaintext with known English words, then you've probably successfully decrypted it and can stop.

Note that even with a 16 bit key, depending on how the encryption was done, this is not entirely trivial to do, as you still need to know something about the encryption method.

Comment: For an initial scan it is usually enough to look for a departure from random in the trial decryption.  With an English plaintext the vast majority of bytes in the correct plaintext are on the range 0x32 to 0x7F.  Any trial with over 75% of bytes in that range is worth a further look using a dictionary.